# Quantile function for negative input

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

Suppose that I have $$\phi(-x)=1-c$$ where $\phi$ is the $N(0,1)$ cdf and $0\leq c \leq 1$. To find $x$ by applying the quantile function, do I then have $$-x = z_{1-c}\rightarrow x = -z_{1-c}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The answer you provide is right.

From another perspective, by the property of $\phi(x)$, it can be shown $\phi(-x) = 1 - \phi(x)$, then $\phi(x) = c$ in your problem. Thus, $x = z_c = -z_{1-c}$.